# Проблемы с USB midi кабелем. Подключение к электрическому фортепиано, что не имеет USB разъёма

Tags: usb, информатика

У меня возникла проблема с таким переходником.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Цифровое пианино - Orla stage talent), так же нет отверстия для USB, поэтому приобрёл данный переходник, однако при подключении (правильном) диод USB горит зелёным при подключении, всё отлично, но с Midi in и out что-то не так. Красный диод in горит постоянно, однако постоянно мигает. Синий же in загорается периодически (теперь еще меньше стал). При включении виртуального пианино на ноутбуке ноты лишь изредка являлись теми, что нажимал (Теперь вообще не работает). Драйвера установились автоматически. Asio было установлено мной.

Answer (score 0):

100% рабочий вариант: покупаете внешнюю usb звуковую карту и в нее подключаете ваше пианино.
Вообще достаточно странно иметь такую махину и не иметь хорошей звуковой карты для минимизации задержки.

Comment: Здравствуйте, благодарю за ответ, однако не могли бы вы немного подробней рассказать об этом варианте. Например, какую внешнюю USB карту лучше всего приобрести, или какие драйвера больше подойдут для моего циф. пианино (все сайты перерыл, однако информации о Orla stage talent практически нет. Даже на официальном сайте данная версия более не присутствует). Уверены ли вы, что с этим переходником не стоит возиться? Многие пользователи довольны покупкой. Ещё у меня нет возможности приобретать затратные покупки.. Буду вам очень благодарен за помощь, мне не к кому обратиться за помощью в этой сфере.

Comment: Например аудиокарта Focusrite Scarlett 2i4.Подключаете midi in/out на вашем цифровом пианино и midi in/out на аудиокарте соответствующим кабелем, карту подключаете по usb в компьютер.

Еще возможно вы ожидаете какой-то другой результат от подключения через MIDI-интерфейс...У вас установлены программы для возможности работы с midi данными(например: cubase,reaper,fl studio)?

Comment: Попробуйте установить любую из перечисленных программ и записать midi-дорожку.После чего откройте её для редактирования и посмотрите верны ли те ноты что вы сыграли.

Comment: и да, про XLR кабель я погорячился :)

Comment: Программы можно найти на рутрекере(Если конечно вы не чураетесь пиратства).

Comment: по моему так это все ответ а не комментирий

Comment: Видите ли, я работаю в FL Studio уже несколько лет, при этом, множество раз задумывался о приобретении подходящего переходника. Как я уже говорил, моё цифровое пианино не вмещает в свой состав usb гнездо. Вот, наконец-то я решил взяться за это дело. Ну, а о дальнейшем Вы уже осведомлены. Еще я упомянул о проблеме с приобретением дорогих вещей, в следствии которой я остановился на мысли потратить как можно меньшую сумму. И вот, я совершил эту покупку.

Comment: Я это к тому, что, возможно, мне стоит убедится в неисправности данного кабеля. Как мне кажется, я просто чего-то, как всегда, не учел. Может быть, он вовсе и не бракован.. (Ну, в противном случае, мне нужно будет задуматься о приобретении аудиокарты.)

Comment: У вас в настройках миди-каналов в fl вообще показывает ваше пианино?